# Two dimentional key value array in VB

Tags: arrays, vb6

In PHP I can have an array with a string as the index and an array as the value, like so:

```
array(
    '01-01-2016' => array(0,1,2,3,4),
    '01-01-2016' => array(0,1,2,3,4),
    '01-01-2016' => array(0,1,2,3,4),
    '01-01-2016' => array(0,1,2,3,4),
    '01-01-2016' => array(0,1,2,3,4)
);
```

Is there an equivalent in VB6?

Comment: Use Scripting.Dictionary (include "Microsoft Scripting Runtime" into project references), store your arrays as values there.

Comment: use collection object

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use collection, any other functionalities as to get item key (obj.key) you have to implement it by yourself, to extend collection object you have to implement the collection using the keyword `implement` then extend it.

for now you can do this:

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim col As New Collection
    Dim a,b 
    col.Add Array("1", 2, 3, 4), "key1"
    col.Add Array("11", 12, 13, 14), "key2"
    col.Add Array("21", 22, 23, 24), "key3"
    For Each a In col

        For Each b In a
            Debug.Print b;
        Next
        Debug.Print vbCrLf & "-----------"
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

IMO, Dictionary is a more straightforward solution than Collection. One of the limitations of the Collection object is that you can't get the index of the values in the Collection directly, as mileyvo has mentioned.  The Dictionary object doesn't have this limitation.  Dictionaries are also faster: see [this](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=220514).  This link also explains how to access the keys in a Dictionary object.  [Here's](http://www.tek-tips.com/viewthread.cfm?qid=1123181) another useful link.